# ocaml stringOfList using concat

Tags: ocaml

The code I currently have is this where I'm testing stringOfList function

```
let rec sepConcat sep sl = match sl with
   | [] -> ""
   | h :: t -> 
       let f a x = a^sep^x in
       let base = h  in 
       let l = t in  
         List.fold_left f base l

let stringOfList f l = sepConcat  "; " (List.map f l)
```

The output I'm supposed to get is

```
# stringOfList string_of_int [1;2;3;4;5;6];;
- : string = "[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]"
```

but I'm getting

```
# stringOfList string_of_int [1;2;3;4;5;6];;
- : string = "1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6"
```

What am I doing wrong? How can i add the extra [] inside the parentheses. Sepconcat is supposed to do this

```
# sepConcat ", " ["foo";"bar";"baz"];;
- : string = "foo, bar, baz"

# sepConcat "---" [];;
- : string = ""

# sepConcat "" ["a";"b";"c";"d";"e"];;
- : string = "abcde"

# sepConcat "X" ["hello"];;
- : string = "hello"
```

Comment: It can't be outside the entire thing though. The square brackets have to be inside the "" which makes it confusing for me since I'm getting this right now "1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6" but I need to put the square brackets inside of the "" like "[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]" though i can't change sepConcat.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong, there's just no place in the code that adds the square bracket characters.

I'd say that the square brackets are another punctuation thing like your `sep` parameter.  You might want to pass them in as additional parameters at some level.  Seems like it would be OK to add them as parameters to `sepConcat`--then it would handle all the punctuation.

**Edit**: it's not going to help to pass different values as `sep`.  The separator goes *between* the strings.  From your description, you want the extra brackets to go around the outside of the result.  Not a separator.

**Edit:** The `"` characters are not part of the string.  They are OCaml's way of showing you that the value is a string.

```
# let x = "a";;
val x : string = "a"
# x;;
- : string = "a"
# String.length x;;
- : int = 1
#
```

Any string value will have "" around it when printed by the interpreter.  So there's no way the square brackets can be outside them!

Comment: i can't change sepConcat though, how would i add it

Comment: Add in `stringOfList` then, I guess?

Comment: I've been trying to do that but I can't find a way that would work and compile correctly from what i have so far let stringOfList f l = sepConcat  "; " (List.map f l)

Comment: What is this line doing in `sepConcat`: `let f a x = a ^ sep ^ x`?

Comment: it combines a and x with the separator. sepConcat is supposed to do this # sepConcat ", " ["foo";"bar";"baz"];;
- : string = "foo, bar, baz"

# sepConcat "---" [];;
- : string = ""

# sepConcat "" ["a";"b";"c";"d";"e"];;
- : string = "abcde"

# sepConcat "X" ["hello"];;
- : string = "hello"

Comment: Right, so you know how to combine strings.  You should show something you tried that didn't work.  Otherwise there's no good way to help.

Comment: i tried let stringOfList f l = sepConcat  "[; ]" (List.map f l)

Comment: let stringOfList f l = sepConcat  ["; "] (List.map f l)

Comment: let stringOfList f l = sepConcat  "; " [(List.map f l)]

Comment: let stringOfList f l = sepConcat  "[" ^"; "^"]" (List.map f l)

Comment: none of which worked, I'm confused it should be simple but I haven't found a way, can you just tell me a way. I've been stuck on this function forever.

Comment: It can't be outside the entire thing though. The square brackets have to be inside the "" which makes it confusing for me since I'm getting this right now "1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6" but I need to put the square brackets inside of the "" like "[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]" though i can't change sepConcat

Comment: Let's reason backwards from "[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]". You know that "AlphaBeta" = "Alpha" ^ "Beta". By analogy, "[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]" = "[" ^ "1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6" ^ "]". Going backwards again, "[" ^ ??? ^ "]", where you know what to put for ???.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `stringOfList` to

```
    let stringOfList f l = 
         let str = sepConcat  "; " (List.map f l) in
         "["^str^"]"
```

---

```
   # stringOfList string_of_int [1;2;3;4;5];;
   - : string = "[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]"
```